# Multiple image upload, change name if image already exists

Tags: php, arrays, image, upload

I have a code that changes image names like in the windows systems. If there is a image like cup.jpg, the code changes the name into cup0.jpg.

The problem however, is when I'm uploading many images from array and only some of the images already exist and need to get the name changed.

What changes need to be made for this to work with multiple files?

```
for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['upload']['name']); $i++) {
  $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["upload"]["name"][$i]);
  $images[] = basename($_FILES['upload']['name'][$i]);
}
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
  $i = 0;
  echo " Image exists, changing name.";
  while (file_exists($target_file)) {
    $extension = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $filename = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    $new_filename = $filename . $i . $iterator . '.' . $extension;
    $target_file = $target_dir . $new_filename;
    $i++;
    $images[] = $new_filename;
  }
}
```

I tried adding a loop but the code doesn't work if the array consists of new images and already existing images so only some of the images would need their names changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are you go:

```
 $images = array();
 for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['upload']['name']); $i++) {
    getUniqueName(basename($_FILES["upload"]["name"][$i]),$images);
 }

 function getUniqueName ($name, &$images) {
     $i = 0;
     $extension = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
     $filename = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_FILENAME);

     while (in_array($name, $images)) {
      $name =  $filename . $i . '.' . $extension;  
      $i++;
     }
    /* Need to define $target_dir here */
    $i=0;
    while (file_exists($target_dir.$name)) {
       $name =  $filename . $i . '.' . $extension;  
       $i++;
     }
     $images[]= $target_dir.$name;
   }
```

Comment: I got a blank white page without any error messages with this but I'll try playing around with this as the code looks correct.

Comment: Please enable your error reporting, let me know the error. thanks

Comment: The problem is the server has error reporting off and it can't be changed.